# SQLite AutoInc Field with DataSet Persistent Fields and AppendRecord?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

My `TFDQuery` originally had no fields defined, just a `Select * from Table`.  To add a record I used `DataSource->DataSet->AppendRecord()` setting the `uniqueid` field to 0 as a place holder.

I've now added persistent fields using the Fields Editor; adding them all.  By default it set the `uniqueid` field to `ReadOnly` and `ServerAutoIncrement` field but even if I turn off `ReadOnly` it now says you can't update the `uniqueid` field.  If I disable `ServerAutoIncrement` and `ClientAutoIncrement` it actually tries to use the 0 as the `uniqueid`, ignoring the SQLite auto increment feature.

How do I use `AppendRecord()` to add the new record when setting up the fields with the field editor?

TIA!!